# Hashie::Mash restore from string

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm quite struggling on this issue. I've stored a `Hashie::Mash` into a string, and I'm having a hard time restoring it back as a hash.

Here's the string:

`"--- !map:Hashie::Mash \ncreated_at: Mon Jul 30 15:42:20 +0000 2012\nid: 229965155759439872\nid_str: \"229965155759439872\"\ntext: \"#streetart encore plus impressionnant de plus pr\\xC3\\xA8s http://t.co/lUUmXFYs\"\nsource: <a href=\"http://twicca.r246.jp/\" rel=\"nofollow\">twicca</a>\ntruncated: false\nin_reply_to_status_id: \nin_reply_to_status_id_str: \nin_reply_to_user_id: \nin_reply_to_user_id_str: \nin_reply_to_screen_name: \nuser: !map:Hashie::Mash \n  id: 15762429\n  id_str: \"15762429\"\n  name: Cyroul\n  screen_name: Cyroultwit\n  location: Paris\n  description: alias Cyril Rimbaud, explorateur de TAZ, creative Technologist, fondateur du laboratoire Curiouser, enseignant au CELSA et casseur de mythes publicitaires.\n  url: http://www.cyroul.com\n  protected: false\n  followers_count: 7431\n  friends_count: 1065\n  listed_count: 481\n  created_at: Thu Aug 07 12:05:21 +0000 2008\n  favourites_count: 10\n  utc_offset: 3600\n  time_zone: Paris\n  geo_enabled: false\n  verified: false\n  statuses_count: 12726\n  lang: fr\n  contributors_enabled: false\n  is_translator: false\n  profile_background_color: 1A1B1F\n  profile_background_image_url: http://a0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/6800607/main-cyr.jpg\n  profile_background_image_url_https: https://si0.twimg.com/profile_background_images/6800607/main-cyr.jpg\n  profile_background_tile: false\n  profile_image_url: http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2018752881/tete-etoiles-petit-128_normal.jpg\n  profile_image_url_https: https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2018752881/tete-etoiles-petit-128_normal.jpg\n  profile_link_color: 2FC2EF\n  profile_sidebar_border_color: 181A1E\n  profile_sidebar_fill_color: \"252429\"\n  profile_text_color: \"666666\"\n  profile_use_background_image: true\n  show_all_inline_media: true\n  default_profile: false\n  default_profile_image: false\n  following: false\n  follow_request_sent: false\n  notifications: false\ngeo: \ncoordinates: \nplace: \ncontributors: \nretweet_count: 0\nentities: !map:Hashie::Mash \n  hashtags: \n  - !map:Hashie::Mash \n    text: streetart\n    indices: \n    - 0\n    - 10\n  urls: \n  - !map:Hashie::Mash \n    url: http://t.co/lUUmXFYs\n    expanded_url: http://yfrog.com/nw86guqj\n    display_url: yfrog.com/nw86guqj\n    indices: \n    - 51\n    - 71\n  user_mentions: []\n\nfavorited: false\nretweeted: false\npossibly_sensitive: false\n"`

How can i get the hash back? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you [serialized](http://www.skorks.com/2010/04/serializing-and-deserializing-objects-with-ruby/) the String using YAML. You can deserialize it like this:

```
require "yaml"
require "hashie"

YAML.load(your_string)
```

Comment: @pef: I am astounded that you *unknowingly* serialized that data structure... How can that happen?

Comment: I have no freaking idea. I used this string to store the raw version of the tweet I was using, in case I'd have to reuse it someday. It was serialized while being saved, I guess.