# How to retrieve values from hash:Hashie::Mash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm trying to retrieve the weekly budget sum from this Hashie, without success.

```
#sample hashie
#client_budget_items

849:
- !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  id: 511144069
  weekly_budget: 5
  client_id: 55
850:
- !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  id: 511144064
  weekly_budget: 30
  client_id: 55
851:
- !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  id: 511144066
  weekly_budget: 10
  client_id: 65
852:
- !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  id: 511144070
  client_id: 65
  weekly_budget: 20
```

I tried:

```
weekly_budgets = client_budget_items.map{|y| y[:weekly_budget]}.compact
```

to get all the values in an array, then sum it up, but I keep getting:

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

How do I traverse a Hashie::Mash?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code does nothing currently. Provide something that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan, any tips on how should I improve it? when I try to map the results into a list I get `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`, as i typed in the question

Comment: Provide the minimal code that incorporates the required `require` statements, loads the data into a string (a here-to document is useful for that) and then show how you try to process it. The data is basically [YAML](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) so that documentation explains how to load from a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11726198/128421 also. Try that many times and if you still can't figure it out ask a specific question about it.

Comment: As hints, `weekly_budget` isn't a symbol, and you have to navigate through a nested array in each hash value. And for fun there are https://www.schneems.com/2014/12/15/hashie-considered-harmful.html and https://code.dblock.org/2017/02/24/the-demonic-possession-of-hashie-mash.html

Comment: @theTinMan oh my god man, the second article title made me laugh so hard.
been struggling with this for about two days, on a legacy system. thanks for the links

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles across this hashie hell, this is what I did to solve my problem.

Transform it into an array:

```
by_uniq_client_id = clients_budget_items.values.map{|y| y.uniq{|t| t.client_id }} 

weekly_budgets = by_uniq_client_id.flatten.map{|x| x.weekly_budget}
```

Comment: It's good that you got it working, however this code doesn't match the variable in your question, and it doesn't contribute to a working solution for anyone else searching to solve the same problem.

Comment: [`flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) could be useful. Again, please read the very first and third comments. The code you supply should be runnable, without having to add additional code. On SO we ask and answer questions to help others, not just to satisfy your need. Part of that is providing code that works to demonstrate the problem without anyone having to add additional code to make it work. That is detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.